# Which one of the two solutions is right?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I tried to solve the following initial/boundary value problem of parabolic type,
[image]
which can be found in book ***A Collection of Problems in Mathematical Physics*** of 
B. M. Budak and A. A. Samarskii.

But my solution is a little different from that given by the authors.

Here is my trial.  First, using changes of variables $\xi=x-v_0 t, \eta=t$ and $v(\xi,\eta)=u(\xi+v_0\eta,\eta)=u(x,t),$  I get
\begin{align*}
v_{\eta}&=a^2 v_{\xi\xi} +v_0 v_{\xi}, \qquad 0<\xi,\eta,\\
v(0,\eta)&=\mu(\eta),\qquad 0<\eta,\\
v(\xi,0)&=0,\qquad 0<\xi.
\end{align*}
Then make change of variable $$v(\xi,\eta)=\exp\Big(\frac{-v_0^2\eta}{4a^2}-\frac{v_0\xi}{2a^2}\Big)w(\xi,\eta) ,$$
I derive that
\begin{align*}
w_{\eta}&=a^2w_{\xi\xi}, \qquad \xi,\eta>0,\\
w(0,\eta)&=\exp\left(\frac{v_0^2\eta}{4a^2}\right)\mu(\eta),\qquad \eta>0,\\
w(\xi,0)&=0,\qquad \xi>0.
\end{align*}
Then I solve for $w(\xi,\eta),$ and get
\begin{gather*}
w(\xi,\eta)=\frac{\xi}{2a\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^{\eta} \exp\left(-\frac{\xi^2}{4a^2(\eta-\tau)}+\frac{v_0^2\tau}{4a^2}\right)\mu(\tau) d\tau.
\end{gather*}
Finally, revert the variables, and I have
\begin{align*}
u(x,t)&=v(\xi,\eta)=\exp\left(-\frac{v_0^2\eta}{4a^2}-\frac{v_0\xi}{2a^2}\right)w(\xi,\eta)\\
&=\frac{(x-v_0t)\exp\left(-\frac{v_0(x-v_0t)}{2a^2}-\frac{v_0^2 t}{4a^2}\right)}{2a\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^t \exp\left(\boxed{\frac{v_0^2\tau}{4a^2}}-\frac{(x-v_0t)^2}{4a^2(t-\tau)}\right)\cdot \frac{\mu(\tau)}{(t-\tau)^{3/2}}d\tau.
\end{align*}
But the solution given by Budak's book is like this
[image]

As you can see, the sign of the boxed term of my solution is positive, while the sign of that of Budak's is negative.  I do not know which one is right.
I have checked my result several times and could not find whether I have made mistakes. Can anyone help me?

Comment: without going in and checking myself..you should always try plugging the solution back into the pde/ode and see if a solution matches irrespective of the "solution manual", as "solution manual" may be wrong, and also in the real world we do not always have such a guide ;(.

Comment: @Chinny84, Actually I have checked that the two ``solutions" satisfy PDE and the initial condition. But I do not know how to check the left-boundary condition.